# cache only one image (.png) with ".htaccess" and not all images(.png)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, drupal-7

Hy,
I have in the home of my drupal site an image that i want cache, but if write this in the htaccess:

```
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  </IfModule>
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

it will be cache all files (.png)...

I want cache only one image.png;  so i ask you if there is a way cache only one element with a rule in the ".htaccess" ????
Is possible??

Thank you :))

Bye from italy ;)

**EDIT :**

is possible write also:

```
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch 'image\.png$ sites/all/themess/mysubtheme/images/sm.png'>
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
  </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule> 
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

???

and finally, if i have two images (.png)   (are sm.png e small.png) i write this:

```
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch 'image\.png$ sites/all/themess/mysubtheme/images/sm.png'>
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch 'image\.png$ sites/all/themess/mysubtheme/images/small.png'>
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
  </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule> 
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

**2° EDIT**:

i have write this:

```
 <FilesMatch '(image|small)\.png$'>
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
 </FilesMatch>
```

but if i use "page speed test Google" or "pingdom tool", not result that the image small.png is cached 
Where is the error ? Maybe i need insert the image's url  ???

Comment: There is nothing about the ask :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `FilesMatch` directive to match and target only one file or set of matching files for certain caching behavior:

```
<FilesMatch 'image\.png$'>
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
```

**EDIT:** As per your edited question you can use:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch '(image|sm)\.png$'>
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
  </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: So, if my image is "sm.png" i need write this:

Comment: Did you leave your comment incomplete?

Comment: I need write this? : 
 
     ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
     <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      <FilesMatch 'image\.png$ sm.png'>
       ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
      </FilesMatch>
     </IfModule>
     ## EXPIRES CACHING ##

Comment: yes that's correct but it is better to post code in question rather than in comment.

Comment: i can't use the "Answer you question" so now i edit the first question ;)

Comment: Ahh ok, so i don't write the url of image, but only '(image|name_file)\.png$'  ??                                        And if i want cache two images, i need add <FilesMatch> ? Correct?

Comment: Yes then you can add another `<FilesMatch>` section as shown above.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. This is fully working code snippet that I have provided. You asked a question about exception for one image `image.png` initially. I tried to co-operate by this cannot go forever.

Comment: but not function also for one image :/

Comment: It works pretty well and if it didn't why did you ask a variant for multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

yes but i tried in this way :

1)

```
     <FilesMatch '(image|sm)\.png$'>
      ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
     </FilesMatch>
```

but non function

```
      <FilesMatch "^(sm)\.png$">
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year" 
      </FilesMatch>
```

not funcion